# JavaScript/Typescript: Created Doubly-Sorted Tree from List

Tags: javascript, list, typescript, data-structures, tree

I have an array representing a flattened Tree according to the following model:

```
export interface TreeModel {
  id: number;
  parent: number;
  value: string;
  children?: Array<TreeModel>;
}
```

Example data is as follows:

```
[
  { id: 1,  parent: 5,  value: 'Apple' },
  { id: 2,  parent: 7,  value: 'Carrot' },
  { id: 3,  parent: 10, value: 'Lettuce' },
  { id: 4,  parent: 5,  value: 'Orange' },
  { id: 5,  parent: 0,  value: 'Fruit' },
  { id: 6,  parent: 0,  value: 'Condiments' },
  { id: 7,  parent: 0,  value: 'Vegetables' },
  { id: 8,  parent: 6,  value: 'Salt' },
  { id: 9,  parent: 6,  value: 'Pepper' }
  { id: 10, parent: 7,  value: 'Green Vegetables' },
  { id: 11, parent: 0,  value: 'Microwave' },
  { id: 12, parent: 0,  value: 'Utensils' }
]
```

The data may have any number of nested children.

I would like to create a tree having a structure similar to the following:

[image]

In this structure, everything is sorted alphabetically and nodes that have children are listed at the top.

Using the example data, this would provide the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 6, "parent": 0, "value": "Condiments", "children": [
      {
        "id": 9, "parent": 6, "value": "Pepper"
      }, {
        "id": 8, "parent": 6, "value": "Salt"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 5, "parent": 0, "value": "Fruit", "children": [
      {
        "id": 1, "parent": 5, "value": "Apple"
      }, {
        "id": 4, "parent": 5, "value": "Orange"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 7, "parent": 0, "value": "Vegetables", "children": [
      {
        "id": 10, "parent": 7, "value": "Green Vegetables", "children": [
          {
            "id": 3, "parent": 10, "value": "Lettuce"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2, "parent": 7, "value": "Carrot"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 11, "parent": 0, "value": "Microwave"
  }, {
    "id": 12, "parent": 0, "value": "Utensils"
  }
]
```

How can this be achieved using JavaScript/Typescript/RxJS in the most efficient manner?

Here is what I have tried so far, though the domain is different than my example:

```
  processSavedTrends(savedTrends) {
    const mappedTrends: Array<TreeModel> = this.getMappedTrends(savedTrends);
    from(mappedTrends)
      .pipe(
        groupBy(trend => trend.parent),
        mergeMap(trendGroup => trendGroup.pipe(toArray())),
        map(parentGroup => parentGroup.sort((firstItem, secondItem) => {
          const cleanFirstItem = firstItem.value.trim().toLowerCase();
          const cleanSecondItem = secondItem.value.trim().toLowerCase();
          if (cleanFirstItem < cleanSecondItem) {
            return -1;
          } else if (cleanFirstItem > cleanSecondItem) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        }))
      )
      .subscribe(trendGroup => {
        const trendGroups = [];
        trendGroups.push(trendGroup);
        this.createTreeFromTrendGroups(trendGroups);
      });
  }

  createTreeFromTrendGroups(trendGroups) {
    trendGroups.forEach(group => console.log(group));
  }

  getMappedTrends(savedTrends: Array<SavedTrendModel>): Array<TreeModel> {
    return savedTrends.map((savedTrend: SavedTrendModel) => {
      return {
        id: savedTrend.objectID,
        parent: savedTrend.parentID,
        value: savedTrend.name
      };
    });
  }
```

This provides an array of arrays where the nested arrays are grouped by parent.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you provide the expected result for the example data that you have provided?

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my post and include it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @Senal, I've added some code that I've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

here is what I have https://es6console.com/jjs2nq9p/

```
interface TreeModel {
  id: number;
  parent: number;
  value: string;
  children?: Array<TreeModel>;
}

const oData : TreeModel[] = [
  { id: 1,  parent: 5,  value: 'Apple' },
  { id: 2,  parent: 7,  value: 'Carrot' },
  { id: 3,  parent: 10, value: 'Lettuce' },
  { id: 4,  parent: 5,  value: 'Orange' },
  { id: 5,  parent: 0,  value: 'Fruit' },
  { id: 6,  parent: 0,  value: 'Condiments' },
  { id: 7,  parent: 0,  value: 'Vegetables' },
  { id: 8,  parent: 6,  value: 'Salt' },
  { id: 9,  parent: 6,  value: 'Pepper' },
  { id: 10, parent: 7,  value: 'Green Vegetables' }
]

const build = (pid) => {
  oData.filter(d => d.parent === pid).forEach(d => {
    d.children = oData.filter(c => c.parent === d.id);
    build(d.id);
    if (d.children.length > 0) {
      oData = oData.filter(c => c.parent !== d.id);
      d.children.forEach(c => build(c.id));
    } else {
      delete d.children;
    }
  });
}
build(0);
console.log(JSON.stringify(oData));
```

Comment: That works amazing, thanks! The only extra requirement is to now sort the parent nodes alphabetically to the top.

Comment: thanks. for the sorting, I will leave it to you :-) hope that it is ok. otherwise, let me know.

Comment: I should be able to handle the sorting. In any case, I'll give it a solid attempt before getting back to you. Thanks again :)